# Can anyone explain why I get TypeLoad Exception while using MathNet.com Numerics Library?

Tags: c#, exception, math.net

I get a strange System.Action TypeLoadException while multiplying two matrixes, Can anyone help?

I created a new project in VS2008, 32bit, and changed target framework to 2.0, include MathNet.Numerics.dll and execute the fallowing code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Numerics;
using MathNet.Numerics.Statistics;
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra;
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double;
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double.Factorization;

namespace MathNetTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double[,] A = new double[3, 3];

            A[0, 0] = 1;
            A[0, 1] = 0.2;
            A[0, 2] = 1;
            A[1, 0] = 1.5;
            A[1, 1] = -1.2;
            A[1, 2] = 1.1;
            A[2, 0] = 0.45;
            A[2, 1] = 2.1;
            A[2, 2] = -0.76;

            Matrix XA = new DenseMatrix(A);
            Matrix XB = new DenseMatrix(A);

            Matrix C = (Matrix)(XA * XB); // throws a TypeLoadException 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? Is this a 32 or 64 bit application?

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm using VS2008, 32bit, and I'm trying to compile as a .NET 2.0 application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> #### **Update**
>
> #### MathNet.Numerics requires .NET Framework #4.0 for [System.Numerics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.aspx) support.

I have no such problem on Mono/MS.NET #4.0 (see examples below)

This is with the libs downloaded from [google code](http://download.codeplex.com/Download?ProjectName=mathnetnumerics&DownloadId=172197&FileTime=129475109693200000&Build=18301)

If my answer doesn't help you, check for conflicting versions of MathNet in the GAC, and preferrably set the references t

- Copy Local = true
- Sepcific Version = true

---

#### Mono 2.10.x:

Minimal tetst program (console application):

```
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double[,] A = new double[3, 3];

        A[0, 0] = 1;
        A[0, 1] = 0.2;
        A[0, 2] = 1;
        A[1, 0] = 1.5;
        A[1, 1] = -1.2;
        A[1, 2] = 1.1;
        A[2, 0] = 0.45;
        A[2, 1] = 2.1;
        A[2, 2] = -0.76;

        Matrix XA = new DenseMatrix(A);
        Matrix XB = new DenseMatrix(A);

        Matrix C = (Matrix)(XA * XB); // throws a TypeLoadException 
    }
}
```

Compiled with

```
dmcs -optimize+ -reference:MathNet.Numerics.dll test.cs
```

Runs fine

#### Win64 MS.NET 4.0:

**Update** Also no problem on VS2010 (WinXP 64):

```
T:\lib\Net40>csc test.cs -reference:MathNet.Numerics.dll
Microsoft (R) Visual C# 2010 Compiler version 4.0.30319.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


T:\lib\Net40>.\test.exe
```

Comment: added successfull compile example on Win64

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm using VS2008, 32bit, and I'm trying to compile as a .NET 2.0 application

Comment: AFAICT the zip file contains _explicitely_ Net40 and SL4 binaries only... I doubt whether more is supported

Comment: **Update** No it isn't. MathNet depends on [System.Numerics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.aspx) which is .Net 4.0+

Comment: TypeLoadException is a runtime exception, not a compile-time error.

Comment: @HansPassant: Clear. Of course it is. Which is why I tested _running it_ too. Note that the framework version was a late addition by the OP ?

Comment: Math.NET Numerics: .Net 4.0+, Portable: Silverlight 5+ or Metro;
Math.NET Iridium: .Net 2.0+